# How to tell CMD to do substitution on FOR loop variables?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to do substitution (a la `%VARIABLE:old=new%`) with a FOR loop variable? I cannot find documentation for such a thing, and I have been unsuccessful in *guessing* the syntax.

For example, if I wanted to accomplish this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "delims=, tokens=3" %%c IN ("field1,field2,field3,field4") DO (
    SET "_C=%%c"
    @ECHO !_C:3=_three!
)
```

(selects 3rd field, replaces `3` with `_three`, and prints the substituted value, `field_three`)

Can I do it without the intermediate assignment to a regular variable? How?

(**EDIT**: updated title to make it something other than a yes/no question.)

Comment: Of course, @Endoro. I tried `%%c:3=_three` with the expected (wrong) results of `field3:3=_three`. The syntax that works for regular variables has a "closing" variable marker (`%`) that doesn't exist for FOR loop variables. I don't know what to use to express this desire to CMD. I'd be delighted if there were some documentation that told me how to do it or confirmed my suspicions that it is as unsupported as Pluto's planethood.

Comment: I have never been able to directly replace using the %%var.  I have always had to assign the %%var to an intermediate variable like you have done.  I believe you have found the only viable solution.

Comment: This doesn't work. Have you tried `set "%%c=whatever`  ?  But you can use for loop variables on the right side of the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use substitution on loop variables without assinging them to "normal" variables first.

Comment: No. Just a fundamental lack of evidence how one could possibly apply the syntax `!v:foo:bar!` to a loop variable `%v`.

Comment: I was hoping for better, but this was my surmise as well.